# How to return random multi integer numbers

Tags: swift

I have a quiz program in swift. Everything is working fine but I thought to make it more efficient by using a function instead of taking each item separately!

Your help appreciated!

On the playground, I tried to use :

```
func random( a:Int, b:Int, c:Int) -> (Int, Int, Int)
    return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(a, b, c)))
```

I got an error saying:

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UInt32' with an argument list of type '(Int, Int, Int)'

Comment: What are you trying to do? Generate three different random values & return them? What are `a`, `b`, and `c` for?

Comment: func random(_ n:Int) -> Int
{
    return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(n)))
}
print(random(9)) Instead I want to use 3 variables

Comment: `arc4random_uniform` is obsolete in Swift as of Swift 4's random unification.

Answer (score 5):

You have a couple of issues.

1. You need to generate the three numbers separately and then return a tuple of the three results.  You are only calling `arc4random_uniform()` once.
2. `arc4random_uniform()` takes a single `UInt32` and you are trying to give it the result of passing three `Int`s to the `UInt32` initializer (which is a non-existent initializer).

I'd suggest using `Int.random(in:)` instead of `arc4random_uniform()`:

```
func random(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int) -> (Int, Int, Int) {
    return (.random(in: 0..<a), .random(in: 0..<b), .random(in: 0..<c))
}
```

**Note:** You don't have to explicitly use the `Int` in the call `Int.random(in: 0..<a)` because Swift is able to infer the `Int` from the return type of the function.

**Example:**

```
for _ in 1...20 {
    print(random(a: 2, b: 6, c: 100))
}
```

> ```
> (0, 3, 5)
> (0, 1, 32)
> (0, 1, 90)
> (0, 3, 17)
> (1, 0, 34)
> (0, 1, 78)
> (1, 0, 71)
> (0, 1, 85)
> (1, 0, 27)
> (1, 0, 26)
> (0, 0, 93)
> (0, 1, 46)
> (1, 4, 47)
> (1, 1, 12)
> (0, 2, 21)
> (1, 3, 72)
> (0, 2, 62)
> (0, 5, 50)
> (1, 2, 23)
> (1, 4, 21)
> ```

---

**Alternate implementation**

By taking a variable number of maximum inputs and returning an array, you can flexibly handle any number of randoms needed:

```
func random(maxVals: Int...) -> [Int] {
    return maxVals.map { .random(in: 0..<$0) }
}
```

**Example:**

```
print(random(maxVals: 2, 6, 100))
```

> ```
> [1, 4, 57]
> ```

```
print(random(maxVals: 2, 6))
```

> ```
> [0, 5]
> ```

Comment: You’re welcome @Farisk. Please consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have a function with this signature: `(Int, Int, Int) -> Int`.
The function `arc4random_uniform` has to be applied on UInt32 and not Int.
If you convert a, b, c it will be good !